# python pymssql at windows encode

Tags: python, encoding, pymysql

I connection to Mssql server on python 2.7 by pymssql.
Connection string is:

```
mssql+pymssql://user:pass@server:1433/DB
```

And Collation of server is **Cyrillic_General_CI_AS**.
When i try select from table with column of varchat it return string:

```
u'ÎÎÎ "ÒÎÐÏÅÄÀ"'
```

I did try to convert it with:

```
"ÎÎÎ "ÒÎÐÏÅÄÀ".decode('866')
```

And get output:

```
├О├О├О "├Т├О├Р├П├Е├Д├А"
```

But correct String in database is:

```
ООО "ТОРПЕДА"
```

It seems like each second simbol is correct.
How to get all varchar2 strings at correct encoding?
Thank you

Comment: what about your display environment? you have to use the SAME charset everywhere, or have appropriate translation logic at the borders.

Comment: I try show it by Flask at html page. Select return me incorrect unicode string as i show at first string example. I found example as i can change encoding at connection string: mssql+pymssql://user:pass@server:1433/DB:charset=utf8. But it return the same incorrect unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer after i did post the question:

```
u'ÎÎÎ "ÒÎÐÏÅÄÀ"'.encode('latin1').decode('1251')
```

May be there is a better solution, but after few days of looking i did't found.